# Why are questions closed?

Tags: discussion, closing, closed-questions

I would like to know why questions can be closed in general; it just occurred to me that even if the question does not make sense to you, there is no reason to close it and prevent it from ever being answered by someone else.
What is the point of closing questions?

Comment: That's indeed two questions: whether questions can be closed in general, and whether your question is closed correctly after someone edited it. These two questions could have different answers.

Comment: I didn't mean to ask either of those things, I asked why questions are closed.

Comment: Now if you could tell me why you closed my question that would be much appreciated as well.

Comment: Well, isn't it obvious that some questions should be closed? That's say if the question is not about math at all, then it should be closed and later deleted right? When a question is closed, the close reason is given and the OP can edit and get it reopened.

Comment: Even then, why does it matter?

Comment: ..... because we have standard?

Comment: On the off-chance that it turns out to be a disguised mathematical riddle, shouldn't it be allowed to remain open?

Comment: Yes but why close questions rather than just downvoting or telling the asker what is wrong?

Comment: Is it just a more severe form of punishment? Why is it disadvantageous to allow those questions to remain open?

Comment: The internet tried sites where there was no option to close questions. Read about usenet newsgroups (later Google designed a frontend to the system, with the result that a large number of people thought they were on something called "Google groups", when in fact Google only gave them access to a server). A math related newsgroup became totally useless after a few years. Exactly because everybody was allowed to ask about anything. The last few weeks I checked out the site may be 90% of the traffic was about a few loonies claiming that they have prove Fermat's Last, Collatz or some such

Comment: What's the point of discussing that off chance? In that cases, other uses can vote to reopen that question. But some questions are just completely off topic and should be removed.

Comment: The same thing happened in many other newsgroups. Some people will choose not to behave. That is why SE will not allow sites without closures and deletions of unfit material. That is why veterans will continue to vote to close and delete. Even in the face of other veterans use the site as a free ride ego trip (either about points or some other motive, but nevertheless ignoring the rules).

Comment: @ArcticChar Because I just don't see what harm open questions cause, that's it.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen, In what way did they not behave? Is it just the volume of unnecessary questions being asked?

Comment: Why does it matter if someone thinks they have proven the Collatz conjecture and haven't, cant they just be told that or downvoted?

Comment: Ok, just ignore me .    .     .

Comment: If we do not nip that in the bud, then 93 out of 100 posts on the site will be about totally misguided proofs, rebuttals to such, bickering rebuttals of the rebuttals etc. Never mind the more modern closure reasons we developed for this site. Largely about attempts to outsource homework. For short - we tried that, it did not work. IT WAS HELL. Anyone who knew any math left the site. letting it die a natural death. We will not allow that to happen here. NEVER.

Comment: One word. TROLLS.

Comment: A more modern explanation. If you think the purpose of this site is to get questions answered, then you have come to the wrong place. The purpose of the site is to collect good math. The questions and answers are to be tools serving that end.

Comment: Ok,  sorry to remind you of that, it just seems there should be a better way of preventing it from happening.

Comment: "The purpose of the site is to collect good math" I thought answering questions were still the primary purpose. What do you mean by that?

Comment: Is there an equivalent website designed explicitly for answering questions?

Comment: Quora, yahoo answers and even some cheating websites I guess.

Comment: Are there any same level of expertise as users of this website?

Comment: "Are there any same level of expertise as users of this website?" Probably not.  People with actual skills and knowledge are generally not interested in doing other people's homework for them, and are likely to leave such homework mills rather quickly, for the reasons outlined by @JyrkiLahtonen above.

Comment: So "designed explicitly for answering questions " always results in "doing other people's homework for them" ?

Comment: @AmoebaProteus If anyone can ask any question and expect an answer, the empirical fact is that the service turns into either a homework mill or an echo chamber for crankery (or both).  We are trying to keep that from happening, as was pointed out to you above.

Comment: I'm not saying anyone asking any question can expect an answer.

Comment: @AmoebaProteus Experience has shown that there are some users who will post solutions to posts even if they are of very bad quality. In the absence of closures, they would have a field day. Then, from the perspective of posters, their chances of expecting an answer are very good, and moreover they need not spend much time making a good post.  So you can see by imposing a minor cost on posts (that they be of sufficiently good quality, or else they cannot receive answers) we can get better content and squelch poor content producers.

Comment: If you would link to the question that was closed, Amoeba, we could have a look at it, and at how it was edited, and come to some decision about reverting the edit and/or reopening the question (or possibly explaining to you why it didn't meet site standards even before it was edited). Questions that have been closed can be reopened, even questions that have been deleted can be undeleted, it happens if the post gets edited up to standard or if enough users are convinced it was a mistake to close/delete it.

Comment: I see that you have [mentioned in a comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4377085/is-the-following-infinite-product-of-fractions-of-linear-factors-equal-to-an-exp#comment9156745_4380512) my edit to your question. I will point out that the only thing I did there was [adding the (infinite-product) tag](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4377085/revisions). @GerryMyerson I cannot be sure, but it's possible that it is about [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4377085) - it was [already discussed on meta](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/34554) a bit.

Comment: Seconding Gerry Myerson's advice. Your question may easily be salvageable.

Comment: Somehow I doubt that .

Comment: @rschweib ok thanks for explaining clearly. I was hoping this could be achieved by simply ignoring the 'bad' posts but I understand that this does not always work.

Comment: @MartinSleziak  someone edited it a lot more than that; I thought it was you.

Comment: Don't you remember changing the writing style somewhat and (not intentionally) the meaning as well?

Comment: @AmoebaProteus You can simply have a look at the revision history (which is why I included link to it). In any case, if we have to discuss who edited what, we can [continue in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/19138/2022/2/15) - so that we do not make this comment thread unnecessarily long.

Comment: Regarding your recent edit to this question:  (1) please try to keep questions (both on meta and on the main site) focused on relevant issues---complaints about downvotes are not relevant to your question about why questions are closed, and (2) on meta, votes do not affect your reputation, and mean something different than they don on the main site:  a downvote mean "I disagree"; in this case, I would assume that people are disagreeing with your premise.

Comment: 1)Good to know they don't affect my reputation on the main site but , with respect, in my opinion, it is relevant actually; it suggests that people on this site are so attached to their ability to censor questions even for non-mathematical reasons that they even downvote someone asking about why they need this ability to censor. 2) What is my premise?

Comment: "... it just occurred to me that even if the question does not make sense to you, there is no reason to close it and prevent it from ever being answered by someone else."  You seem to be assuming that questions are closed because people don't understand them.  The tone of your question here is polemical, and I believe that people are reacting to that (I can't speak for anyone else, but that was my reaction).  You seem to continue in that assumption be equating to closure as "censorship".  It strikes me that you are trying to read intention into the actions of others, and are doing it badly.

Comment: This is really about what people think serves the *website* and what they think doesn't. Usually, when someone on MSE writes a question to which they want an answer it's written in a way where most people can see benefit for future readers. Sometimes this doesn't happen, leading to closure. The close reasons are tailored to the librarianship of MSE, so if your goal isn't to maintain the repository, I can understand why you may have used the word "censorship". It isn't , though : five users can vote to reopen as well, questions can be improved, context-rewritten : the options are plenty.

Comment: Question closure really has to do with maintenance of the repository. In particular ,the three facets of a question that MSE focuses upon are (1) the scope of the question (2) the searchability of the question (3) the MSE-based quality of the question. Each of these may be subject to some disagreement, but on the whole opinions are quite well-formed. Anybody whose aim is to maintain the repository will naturally see these as necessary parts of the site.

Comment: @XanderHenderson, I didn't mean to suggest that all or most questions are closed because the person closing doesn't understand, but the point is that it could happen occasionally... maybe 'censor' isn't quite the right word but I can't think of a better alternative to 'close /downvote to provide incentive not to ask' .

Comment: @sarveshRavichandranIyler Could you elaborate on what you mean by the searchability of the question? And I agree that some questions would need to be closed(or removed) if the website were operated like a physical library to prevent, but I can't see how it applies to a digital repository like this website as you do not need to search through 99.99% of questions (the computer does this).

Comment: @AmoebaProteus Ideally, MSE should be a place where one should be able to *already* find an answer to their question, and ask only when it cannot be found. Now, searching for question essentially involves ensuring that someone is directed to the best possible answer when they search for their question. Having the same question asked many times, for example, has the same issue as having a book torn up, and each page being kept as a separate book in the library : so when someone comes to search, they only find bits and pieces but never the complete piece.

Comment: The idea behind preventing duplication, is that if one can link questions that are the same, then a lot of people can make use of , and ratify, one standard source which is comprehensive, answers a lot of people's questions, and doesn't need to be mentioned again and again in different places. Searching is therefore improved by marking and identifying duplicates, and collecting answers to a common question in one place.

Comment: That makes sense, although I would say having the same question asked many times is more like having multiple copies of a book rather than one book torn up because removing pages does not necessarily help put them back together into a complete piece.

Comment: @AmoebaProteus I think we are looking at different notions of a book. For example , is one proof of the irrationality of $\sqrt 2$ a book, or part of another book that contains five more proofs of the same thing? Either way, I would wager that in the presence of a larger book, a smaller book makes sense only if it has a context separated from the bigger book (for example, if someone wanted to understand an argument in much deeper detail) and this doesn't happen very often, really. This at least would explain a part of why duplication is deemed necessary.

Comment: I would agree about the smaller book not making sense if it has no context separated from the larger book, but in most cases larger books won't be expanded to incorporate the content from the smaller books.

Answer (score 19):

It seems that the underlying assumption of the original question here is that questions on the main site are closed because they "don't make sense" to the close voters.  This is an erroneous assumption.

The principle goal of the SE network is to create repositories of discoverable, searchable questions with high quality answers.  The idea is that a user's typical interaction with the site will occur when they search for a question (using the on-site search, or a third-party search engine) and find that it has already been answered.  The goal is for 90%+ of users to never have to ask a question, because their answer is already on the site.

(Note that this is distinct from other services, such as Quora, which seek to answer individual questions as they arise.)

Because the principle goal of the site is to create a searchable database, it is necessary to ensure the quality of that database—we don't want the noise to drown out the signal.  As such, it is necessary to close (and delete) questions which are not a good fit for the site.  There are a number of reasons why a question might be a poor fit:

- the question may be too local (i.e. interesting only to the person asking the question—things like homework problems often fall into this category);
- the question may provide too little detail for a future reader to find it via search;
- the question might be a duplicate of something already asked;
- the question may not provide enough context for *answerers* to understand what kind of answer is actually expected;
- the question may be simply off-topic (i.e. not actually a question about mathematics);
- and so on.

Hence questions are often closed for any one of myriad reasons.  This is part of the basic functionality of the site.

Comment: "It seems that the underlying assumption of the original question here is that questions on the main site are closed because they "don't make sense" to the close voters" No, I didn't mean to imply this, however reasons such as the one after the fourth bullet point  may apply to some answerers but not others... or, as in the case of my question, they might later be edited, changing how much context there is.

Comment: "...or, as in the case of my question, they might later be edited, changing how much context there is."  Which is why it is also possible to *reopen* questions which have been closed.

Answer (score -4):

I'll give a simpler answer, it's because people don't usually specifically 'search' for questions when trying to answer them, it rather pops up in their feed. If a person who has intent to answer sees many questions poorly presented / frame/repeats, their morality of wanting to answer will decrease.

**Side note:**

If there was somehow a neuralink system which would automatically look at the things in our brain and find the answers for questioners (supposing some questioner would be interested in the non standard questions),  then sure, I would agree with what you are saying.